# Cost of Lunar base in today's dollars: reference government report about a lunar base written in 2009?

Tags: lunar-landing, lunar-base

What would the current cost be?

Costs of an International Lunar Base from September 24, 2009

Below is a link:
https://www.csis.org/analysis/costs-international-lunar-base

Comment: The sources are all named at the end of the article?

Comment: I'm voting to close as there's no real question. Have I seen it? No.